# JFormValidator is not defined

Tags: javascript

Getting this error in JS after updating from Joomla 3 to 4. Gonna debug more and post edits/answer here if I find it. If anyone knows already, feel free to tell!

Comment: Possibly missing `$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->useScript('form.validate');`